# Run time Error 1004 when checkbox checked / unchecked

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook with two sheets, "Scores" & "Assets". There are Active X checkboxes on "Scores" which just display MsgBox when checked. 
I have this very simple code to create a dropdown list on "Scores" with values on "Assets".

```
Sub testlist()

Dim scoresDatas As Range
Dim scoresList As Range

Set scoresDatas = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Assets").Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Assets").Cells(4, 1), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Assets").Cells(8, 1))
Set scoresList = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scores").Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scores").Cells(8, 4), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scores").Cells(8, 4))

With scoresList.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="='" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Assets").name & "'!" & scoresDatas.Address
End With

scoresList.Value = 0
scoresList.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter


End Sub
```

If I open the workbook, don't touch to the checkboxes, the sub works, no matter on which sheet the workbook is. But, this is the weird part, If i check / uncheck checkboxes then the code will work only if the sheet "Assets" is activated. If I'm on "Scores" i have a Run time error 1004 on the line `.Add`

If someone know why, it would be great ! Thanks !

EDIT : I didn't replace "thisworkbook..." on purpose to avoid referencing problem while i was testing
EDIT 2 : This code is not related to the checkboxes

Comment: If memory serves, you cannot directly refer to a range in another sheet using DV. You have to use a named range.

Comment: Sorry not native english here, what do you mean by "if memory serves" ? And If i can't, why does it work before I touch to the checkboxes ?

Comment: How is this code related to your checkboxes?

Comment: it's not related at all !

Comment: I think I'm talking nonsense - just tested and your code works for me. I'm confused. Why does this code run at all when you change your checkboxes?

Comment: That's my main queston ahah

Comment: What does error 1004 say? And what happens if you insert `Range("A1").Select` before the `With scoresList.Validation`?

Comment: And where is this sub located (in a Sheets code or in a modules code)?

Comment: It says "application defined or object defined error". It's in a module code. It works with `Range("A1").Select` and with `scoresList.select`also but i would like to avoid select in my code

Comment: So you didn't want to chat with me after all. This might be one occasion when you need to use select.

Comment: I've clicked by curiosity on the chat link, sorry ! Yes, apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if a checkbox or any other control is selected this line will fail

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="='" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Assets").name & "'!" & scoresDatas.Address
```

Therefore you need to make sure that a cell instead of a control is selected. Eg. by running `Range("A1").Select` before the line above.

Instead make sure that you click on a cell after clicking the checkbox and before you run the sub.

Comment: I think i have no choice to avoid to use select here. 
Thanks !

Comment: `Select` is not bad/evil at all. It is just bad practice to select if it can be avoided.